# Android Jetpack Compose: How to avoid absorb click when @Composable has alpha to 0?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

The idea is to have a *segmented button* that basis on the selected index shows `MapScreen` or `ListScreen`.

I use `alpha` to avoid **re-composable** of the map when switching and because on startup I show the list and in the background load the Map and everything connected to it.

The problem is that when `ListScreen` `alpha is 1` the `MapScreen` **absorb the same the clicks** and is impossible to select the item of the list.

How to solve this problem?

Thanks in advance for the response.

```
Box() {

      ListScreen (
        modifier = Modifier.alpha(if (selectedSegmentControlIndex.value == 0) 1f else 0f))

      MapScreen (
        modifier = Modifier.alpha(if (selectedSegmentControlIndex.value == 1) 1f else 0f)
      )
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that there is no clean solution because you don't follow the compose guidelines when you're trying to avoid recomposition.

But if that's necessary you can pass **isVisible: Boolean** as a param in **MapScreen**. Then you can disable all click interceptors if flag equals false.